# Falied to start Red5 in openmeetings Unregistering JMX-exposed beans

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, red5, openmeetings

I'm trying to install apache openmeetings_3.1.1 on ubuntu 12.04

But I can't start openmeeting,

```
# /etc/init.d/red5 start
start-stop-daemon: --start needs --exec or --startas
Try 'start-stop-daemon --help' for more information.
```

No errors on the command line 
I checked log file on `/usr/lib/red5/log/red5.log` 
I found this error

```
2016-05-25 11:58:28,459 [main] INFO  o.r.spring.Red5ApplicationContext - Closing ApplicationContext 'red5.common': startup date [Wed May 25 11:58:27 EET 2016]; parent:   org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@5d3c19e3
2016-05-25 11:58:28,462 [main] INFO  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2016-05-25 11:58:28,462 [main] INFO  o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2016-05-25 11:58:28,463 [main] INFO  o.s.j.s.ConnectorServerFactoryBean - Stopping JMX connector server: javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer@3e98ae8d
2016-05-25 11:58:28,465 [main] INFO  o.s.j.s.ConnectorServerFactoryBean - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2016-05-25 11:58:28,465 [main] INFO  o.s.r.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean - Unexporting RMI registry
2016-05-25 11:58:28,466 [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler Red5_Scheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutting down.
2016-05-25 11:58:28,473 [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler Red5_Scheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED paused.
2016-05-25 11:58:28,474 [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler Red5_Scheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED shutdown complete.
```

Can anyone till me what this error mean and how can I fix it ?

Comment: This will be fixed soon, we have discontinued the use of the RMI connector in Red5; I'll ping one of the OM devs about it.

Answer (score 0):

what script are you using as "/etc/init.d/red5" ?

here is the list for installing various versions of OM for different OSes: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OPENMEETINGS/Tutorials+for+installing+OpenMeetings+and+Tools

start-stop-daemon is usually installed on Ubuntu.

3.1.2 release most probably will have modified start-stop script as @Paul have mentioned